# Can a Thai citizen with US green card visit Canada?

Tags: canada

Can my Thai wife with US permanent green card visit Canada with me?  Taking an Alaskan cruise.

Comment: Removed the confusing and untrue part of the title: there's no visa to be gotten on arrival. Otherwise, welcome to beautiful British Columbia, hope you will enjoy your stay here, no matter how brief.

Answer (score 3):

Yes she can.  Green card holders do not need a visa to visit, only their green card when cruising (though it wouldn't hurt to have her passport with you as well).

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16